# Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityRoleClaim<int>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a custom Identity for a already made Database and it is working for users logging in that do not have roles, but users with roles, it displays this error.

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityRoleClaim' because this type
>   is not included in the model for the context

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationIdentityUser, CustomRole>()
            .AddUserStore<CustomUserStore<ApplicationIdentityUser>>()
            .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager<ApplicationIdentityUser>>()
              .AddRoleStore<CustomRoleStore<ApplicationIdentityUser>>()
              .AddRoleManager<CustomRoleManager>()

            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AhUserContext, int>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddMvc()
          .AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
          .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();


        //Add the custom Password Hasher
        services.AddScoped<PasswordHasher<ApplicationIdentityUser>, CustomPasswordHasher<ApplicationIdentityUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<IdentityRole<int>, CustomRole>();
        services.AddScoped<IdentityRoleClaim<int>, CustomIdentityRoleClaim>();
        services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationIdentityUser>, CustomSignInManager<ApplicationIdentityUser>>();
        services.AddScoped<IdentityUserClaim<int>, CustomIdentityUserClaim>();
        services.AddScoped<IdentityUserLogin<int>, CustomIdentityUserLogin>();
        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftAzureStorage"));

        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Custom Identity Classes

```
public class ApplicationIdentityUser : IdentityUser<int>{} 
public class CustomIdentityRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<int>
public class CustomIdentityUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
public class CustomIdentityUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int>
public class CustomRoleManager : RoleManager<CustomRole>
public class CustomRoleStore<ApplicationIdentityUser> : RoleStore<CustomRole, AhUserContext, int>
public class CustomSignInManager<IUser> : SignInManager<IUser> where IUser : ApplicationIdentityUser
public class CustomUserManager<IUser> : UserManager<IUser> where IUser : ApplicationIdentityUser
public class CustomUserStore<IUser> : UserStore<IUser, CustomRole, AhUserContext, int> where IUser : ApplicationIdentityUser
```

Comment: What does your context (`AhUserContext`?) look like? What does it inherit from?

Comment: AHUserContext is a DBContext

Comment: It needs to inherit from `IdentityDbContext<....>`

Comment: Changing to IndentityDBContext, still gives the same error

Comment: I assume you used `IdentityDbContext<int>` instead of `IdentityDbContext<x,y,z,etc.....>` which is the one you need if you want to use custom objects?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
public class CustomRoleStore<ApplicationIdentityUser> : RoleStore<CustomRole, AhUserContext, int>
```

to

```
public class CustomRoleStore<ApplicationIdentityUser> : RoleStore<CustomRole, AhUserContext, int, CustomIdentityUserRole, CustomIdentityRoleClaim >
```

I had the same issue. Because I had both a custom UserManager as well as RoleManager, both had to propagate up the inheritance chain properly for it all to work.